# What is the purpose of not accept of getting zero and initialize them in to fractional part in dataset KNN Algorithm?

Tags: pandas, numpy, knn

here's the code. I just want to know what the for loop actually do and whats the purpose of it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('E:/CV (ALL FOR JOB)/ALL PROJECTS/5. IMAGE DETECTION/KNN_Dataset.CSV')
df
df.head()
print(len(df))
zero_not_accepted = ['Glucose', 'BloodPressure', 'SkinThickness', 'BMI', 'Insulin']


for column in zero_not_accepted:
    df[column] = df[column].replace(0, np.NaN)
    mean = int(df[column].mean(skipna=True))
    df[column] = df[column].replace(np.NaN, mean)

X = df.iloc[:, 0:8]
y = df.iloc[:, 8]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply replaces the zeros by the mean of the column computed without those zeros.

An alternative method could be:

```
# mask the zeros
m = df[zero_not_accepted].mask(df[zero_not_accepted].eq(0))
# replace the masked values by the mean
df[zero_not_accepted] = m.fillna(m.mean(skip a=True))
```